# Are there mechanisms in mysql to limit INSERT based on arbitrary value

Tags: mysql

If I want to limit number of entries per user in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `connections` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `word_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `No duplicates` (`user_id`,`word_id`),
  KEY `word_id` (`word_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `connections_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `connections_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`word_id`) REFERENCES `words_en` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this limit can change and I store it in another table called settings.

Should I do first SELECT and than do php compare and than INSERT. or is there a mechanism to do this kind of operations directly in INSERT query?

Comment: Do a trigger which counts rows per user and if > than some value delete the older entries.Assuming deleting is an option.

Comment: @Mihai can I set that value in another table for trigger to use? Can you give me example of this kind of trigger? Is it recommended to keep this kind of issues within sql, or php way I described is recommneded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
create
  trigger `some trigger` AFTER INSERT
  on table
  for each row begin
  if (select count(id) from someothertable)>=100 then
    delete from table  WHERE id = NEW.id -99;  
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I`m afraid I`m out of my depth,I think I could do it given enough time for research,but you`d better ask somebody more informed.Here is my half-assed trigger,not tested.

There is also Create Event in mysql you could use.http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Comment: ok, I'm reading about triggers now. Thanks! I will test this and write here how it works out.